# SUBMIT form using post method without ajax (jquery mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm doing login form which looks like:

```
<head> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../sp/jqm/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.extend(  $.mobile , {
            ajaxFormsEnabled: false,
            ajaxEnabled: true
        });
    });
```

```
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../sp/jqm/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b"> 
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div> 
        <div data-role="content">
            <form action="login_act.asp" method="POST" id="frm_prijava" name="frm_prijava">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="username"> User name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""  />
                    <label for="pass">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value=""  />
                    <input type="submit" name="sbm" id="sbm" data-role="button" value="Enter" /> 
                </div>
            </form>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</body>
```

When i try to submit form, dialog pops up and nothing happens... it just loads the page...

how can I submit this form without ajax?

Comment: I don't think that AJAX is turned on or managed by default. Please send us more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing your mobileinit event before jQuery Mobile is loaded

The mobileinit event is triggered immediately upon execution, you'll need to bind your event handler before jQuery Mobile is loaded.

Cheers

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out... the problem was with the page that I was loading...